# Use of ajax framework to develop a webapp employing php, codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, frameworks

I am going to start developing a webapp using php framework codeigniter. The app is going to do most of the database dealing using ajax/jquery. From what I know, I would be implementing the following steps to do a particular task

1. Create a view page
2. The events performed on view page's elements, i.e., click, mouseover etc. will be attached to event handler functions in js files included in the view
3. js functions will be making get, post requests to server side
4. In case some dynamic values need to be passed to js functions they'll passed using inline php code given below.
5. On server side, some database queries will be performed to generate a json(sometimes xml) which will be sent as response
6. Based on the response, the js function callback will manipulate the dom.

Now, my question is whether there is an ajax framework that can further simplify the implementation of steps given above. if not a framework, then may be a better approach to implementing ajax and php.

```
// This is part of view page
<a href="Delete User" onclick="deleteUser('<?php echo $userid; ?>')" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by "AJAX framework" and whether you're talking about a clientside or serverside framework.

In the event you're looking for a clientside framework that handles client-server data synchronization, check out http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Even I haven't heard of such a framework its just a terminology which might help simplify my development process or may be provide better structure to the mesh of php, jquery and html I'm about to create.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/). This is not an AJAX framework (I have never heard of one of those) but it is a JavaScript Framework that incorporates some easy AJAX functionality.

Everyone talks about "integrating with the PHP framework!" like its some sort of crazy feature in PHP. JavaScript makes a request to a URL and does something with the response. That URL could be native PHP, CodeIgniter, a static file or bloody ColdFusion, it is all the same.

So if you are using CodeIgniter, in your view put:

```
$.get('/controller/method/param1/param2', function(data) {
  $('div#someid').text(data.whatever);
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has a javascript class that might help avoid "the Mess" you spoke of.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

Comment: I would strongly suggest you do not use this class as your primary method of writing jQuery, that would be ridiculous.

Comment: @Phil, it is a given you have VASTLY more experience than I do.  So I'm curious why you say that.  I'm not disagreeing, but since the OP got me thinking about giving the jquery class a try, I'd like to know NOW (before I'm knee deep in a bad idea) why it is to be avoided.

Comment: The problem is that you're writing JavaScript in PHP! JS is a strong language with a very powerful, flexible syntax. Building your JavaScript with $this->jquery is handy for small little effects but you really wouldn't want to use it as your main solution. Use it for things like, on form submission slide up a box with one line instead of passing a var to the view then writing a <script> tag for it. Basically it should be used in moderation, not all the time.